# to be better vs to get (feel) better

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

> Julia has been ill, but now she's beginning _______ better.

The answer is "**to feel**" or "**to get**".

Could you explain if I can use "**to be**"?

Source: English Grammar in Use by Raymond Murphy, Unit 56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying "beginning to be better" is grammatically correct, but it is a weak word to use. I'd understand what you meant, but "feel better" is a much clearer phrase, if you are talking about her feelings and how she is experiencing the effect of the illness.

And "get better" is an idiom that means exactly "return to health".

Moreover "be" tend to have a "static" sense which doesn't pair well with the dynamic "beginning".

So you should not use "be".